# After Ubuntu Upgrade, cannot connect to wifi(wireless)

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I upgraded my Ubuntu OS from an ISO. Initially, my connection kept on dropping. After a while, ubuntu failed to connect to wireless at all.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall drivers.

sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms patch fakeroot bcmwl-kernel-source

Reference: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11410285&postcount=36