# Cannot connect to wifi after upgrade to 13.10 (BCM4313)

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

[**Edit:** the solution provided by chili555 solved my problem. However, note that I further had to remove the drivers "brcmsmac" and "bcma" from blacklisting in order  for them to load at each boot (files "broadcom-sta-common.conf" and "blacklist-brcmsmac.conf", not sure it is needed for both files though...). Hope this won't lead to any conflicts.]

I've just upgraded my ubuntu from 12.04 to 13.10 by successive upgades.
My main problem after those is that I have trouble to connect to wireless.

Looking through the net, I saw that many people already met this problem, but neither of the methods i tried to fix it did work:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx
- [After Ubuntu Upgrade, cannot connect to wifi(wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216750/after-ubuntu-upgrade-cannot-connect-to-wifiwireless)
- [13.10 BCM4313 network problems after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368448/13-10-bcm4313-network-problems-after-update)

The main effect of the bcmwl-kernel-source driver re-installation (whatever was by the "Softwares & Updates" desktop menu or [by the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A12.04_.28Precise_Pangolin.29_-_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29)) was to allow the Broadcom card to be detected. Unfortunately, my laptop is still not able to connect to the wireless networks (like for the question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/378308/can-find-network-but-cannot-connect-to-it-ubuntu-13-10)

Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any help about that! Many thanks in advance.

Here some details of my hardware and drivers:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

$ uname -a
Linux ludo-E6530 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And the wireless network section of

```
sudo lshw

       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: eth1
            version: 01
            serial: 08:3e:8e:50:1c:ee
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
            resources: irq:17 memory:f7600000-f7603fff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try the other possibility. With a temporary wired ethernet connection:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: Yeah, that works great! However, note that I had to remove the drivers "brcmsmac" and "bcma" from blacklisting (files "broadcom-sta-common.conf" and "blacklist-brcmsmac.conf", not sure it is needed for both files though...). I'll edit my question to give this precision. Thanks again.

Comment: If you purge bcmwl-kernel-source, the wrong driver for 14e4:4727, it is supposed to entirely remove the broadcom-sta-common.conf file.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but it appears that this file wasn't removed by purging...This can be linked to my initial problem but I have no idea why to be honest...

Comment: Thanks! This solution works just great on 15.04 for my BRCM4313

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help, but i notice you did not install linux hearders.
Install linux headers and then reinstall bcmwl:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After that log out and log in again.

Comment: Thanks rat2000, but unfortunately the linux headers were already installed: 
    
    "linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded".

I tried to re-install the bcmwl anyway but it still doesn't work :(