# Wireless not working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10, but the wireless is not working and no wireless networks are showing:

Command: iwconfig
Outputs:

```
eth0 no wireless extensions.

eth1 IEEE 802.11abg EEID:off/any
     Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power-19 dBm
     Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
     Power Management:off

lo   no wireless extensions.
```

The lspci -nn | grep 0280

Outputs:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless
Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Command lsmod | grep -e b43 -e brcm -e wl
Outputs:

```
wl          4207474         0
lib802011   14352           2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkit
cfg80211    479757          1 wl
```

The following commands:
sudo -i
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit

Output is:

```
youssef@YoussefSiblini:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for youssef: 
root@YoussefSiblini:~# apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source
root@YoussefSiblini:~# echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
root@YoussefSiblini:~# ^C
root@YoussefSiblini:~#
```

The out put of: lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl  and rfkill list all

```
youssef@YoussefSiblini:~$ lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl
brcmsmac              562767  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              596969  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              479757  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
bcma                   46670  2 brcmsmac
youssef@YoussefSiblini:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Many thanks in advance.

Youssef

Comment: Please edit your question to include: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e brcm -e wl. I do not think this is a duplicate at all. Thanks.

Comment: That is master question for all broadcom wireless driver, the second answer covers all. However, there is a bug. bcmwl-kernel-source version 6.20 doesn't work above 12.04. Solution is given in the following question - [Broadcom BCM4313 on 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/316072)

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/405285/cannot-connect-to-wifi-after-upgrade-to-13-10-bcm4313) may help.

Comment: Ethernet connection is not working too

Comment: @Web-E The master question has much conflicting and absolutely incorrect information. How is a user supposed to wade through 38 answers to find one that is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
echo "blacklist b43" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us have your report.

Does your ethernet start up if you try:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig
```

Is ethtool installed?

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100
```

If the ethernet is now working:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you still are unable to connect the ethernet, blacklist wl:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist wl" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
modprobe brcmsmac
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your result.

Comment: Thanks, I did the following commands and added the output in my question.

Comment: More Details: when I click on the network icon it says: WI-FI networks disconnected and when I restart it says: Disconnected you are now offline netwrok.

Comment: What is your ethernet device? lspci -nn | grep 0200

Comment: 01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)

Comment: One more thing I should have mentioned it earlier, my laptop monitor stopped working so I am using external monitor with hdmi connection

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Hi chili555 sorry for the delay, as I was suspicious of my internet cable I rushed to the shop and I got new one, the good news is that  I am able to connect to the internet using the new cable, but still no luck with the wireless, I have tried the commands above and still no luck.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Still no luck, no idea why it is not working I've tried every thing.

Comment: After the blacklists and loading brcmsmac, what does this say? lsmod | grep -e brcm -e b43 -e wl and also: rfkill list all Thanks.

Comment: Please see the 'The out put of: lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl  and rfkill list all' section in my question.

Comment: After a fresh reboot so we have a clean slate, please run: dmesg > wifi.txt. Find the file wifi.txt in your user directory and paste it here. Give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7175815/

Comment: Please update brcmsmac as here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191126&page=2&p=12889620#post12889620

Comment: Can we clean comments?

Comment: yep :) off course